# Notifications Not Going Out

Tags: jira

I've been trying to figure this out for a week now and haven't had any success. I have a project in Jira with a Kanban board that we use for issues/support tickets. We have a custom field (called secondary assignee) which basically lets us add an additional assignee responsible for the ticket.

I am trying to figure out how to set Jira to send an email notification to the secondary assignee when the requester or someone else replies to the issue and the issue is updated. Our settings are as follows:

*Project -> Notification Settings -> Events -> Issue Updated -> Notification: User Custom Field Value (Secondary Assignee)*

This should ensure that the notification goes out to the secondary assignee when an issue is updated.

*Project -> Permissions -> Secondary Assignee has permissions to browse projects*

I've also tried using the notification helper (system settings) on a ticket where I am the secondary assignee and the helper indicates I should be receiving e-mails when an issue is updated. However, I am still not receiving any notifications.

Does anyone have an idea what else to look at?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Each Jira user has a setting in the Profile about Notify Me. So you may not be getting emails about issues you change

Comment: So as an admin for the project I'd have to modify settings for each user in that project? I'm not really sure what you mean by Jira users in this case. I would like to send these notifications to the secondary assignee by default, regardless of who they are.